# Can we change the video driver?

Tags: drivers, graphics, video

Can we change the default Ubuntu video driver?

I use Ubuntu Studio 15.10 and I discovered some issue with this driver when I use Google Earth.

Specifically, the system tells me that my video card doesn't support some specs.

BUT... When I use the same PC, with the same video card, but under Windows 7, I don't have any problem!

Is there another video driver(s) available to Ubuntu? Where?

The System Info app of Ubuntu tells me that my video card is:

```
VGA Compatible Controller

Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core Processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

(prog-if 00 [VGA Controller])

Subsytem: Micro-Star Internatonal Co., Ltd. [MSI] 
Device MS-7788
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the Intel graphics installer, from there website, 15.10 supports the latest version of the driver

For a 64bit OS, run

```
wget https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/15.10/main/pool/main/i/intel-linux-graphics-installer/intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.2.1-0intel2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.2.1-0intel2_amd64.deb
intel-linux-graphics-installer
```

On 32 bit, you can run

```
wget https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/15.10/main/pool/main/i/intel-linux-graphics-installer/intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.2.1-0intel2_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.2.1-0intel2_i386.deb
intel-linux-graphics-installer
```

This will run a graphical installer and install the latest driver, however, you may find that 3D acceleration for these chips, just simply is not at the levels it on Windows, but it is getting better quickly.

[image]

Comment: I did it, but I got a 404, not found error message. Are you sure the address is right? ???

Comment: I found the right address on google: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.2.1

Comment: **https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.2.1**. This is the right address to download the Intel Graphics driver for Linux. BUT... I don't know if I win something with this. At least, the GoogleEarth issue (something about polygons and some OpenGL specs) is still the same. When I see some UltraHD video, I don't feel any significant change in comparison with the "old" driver. SO... I don't know if to download and install this driver was a good decision. Just in case... Can I come back to the "old" driver? ???

Comment: URLs for wget are dead

Comment: @cutrightjm The answer is outdated as 15.10 is eol now, here is the link for the newer versions https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.2